# How to create an instance of concrete class from static method of abstract class

Tags: typescript

I try to create an instance of concrete class from static method of abstract class. But I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null:
>   undefined

On this line of code in ConcreteClass.js: **return extendStatics(d, b);**

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
```

My project files:

Program.ts

```
import { AbstractClass } from "./AbstractClass";

class Program
{
    public static Main()
    {
        let instance = AbstractClass.CreateObject();
        instance.Method();
    }
}
Program.Main();
```

AbstractClass.ts

```
import { ConcreteClass } from "./ConcreteClass";

export abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public static CreateObject()
    {
        return new ConcreteClass();
    }

    public abstract Method(): void;
}
```

ConcreteClass.ts

```
import { AbstractClass } from "./AbstractClass";

export class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass
{
    public Method() : void
    {
        console.log("Method of ConcreteClass");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has to do with a circular import. `AbstractClass` and `ConcreteClass` are importing each other and the definition of each is making use of the other. The specific problem is that when `ConcreteClass` is extending `AbstractClass`, the `AbstractClass` is still undefined, because it is waiting for `ConcreteClass` to finish loading. As a result, the runtime is seeing something like vaguely this:

```
import { AbstractClass } from "./AbstractClass";

// at runtime AbstractClass has not finished loading yet so it is undefined
export class ConcreteClass extends undefined
{
    public Method() : void
    {
        console.log("Method of ConcreteClass");
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not hear about the circular import problem before. Now I understand what I need to search in the Internet. Thank you very much.